# Importing documents in our app from iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to import some document in my app from iPhone something like PDF file or  From another app ? is any way to do this ?
any link about that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link about allowing the app to share its documents folder with itunes.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Alternatively you could use code in your app to write files into the apps "documents" directory directly. If neither of these two things are what you are looking for you can register your app to support a file format? But that doesn't sound like what you want.

```
- (NSString*)DocumentsPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE);  
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

//not every class supports writeToFile
- (void)writeToFile:(id)object withFileName:(NSString*)filename
{
    [object writeToFile:[[self DocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:TRUE];
}
```